# Live schema migrations on Cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, database-migration, production-environment

I have a cluster of 3 Cassandra instances and 3 instances of the web server connected to each of Cassandra instances respectively, in 3 availability zones on AWS. I want to update the schema of Cassandra, which is incompatible with the current version of web application, with very little downtime (seconds), or better yet completely without downtime.

So far I've came up with the following plan:

1. Remove one instance of web app from the load balancer
2. Remove correspondent Cassandra instance from the cluster with `nodetool disablegossip`
3. Apply migrations on the Cassandra node from step `2`.
4. Update web app from step `1` to current version.
5. Remove the two other instances of web app from the load balancer
6. Return the update web app instance from step `1` to load balancer
7. Return the Cassandra node from step `2` to cluster with `nodetool enablegossip`, letting it propagate the schema change to other nodes
8. Update the two other instances of web app to the current version
9. Return them to the load balancer
10. Done

Could you please point any flaws in this approach? From what I can see, there'll be some downtime between steps 5 and 6, but probably not very long one. Besides that, are there any other problems here? And is it possible to do better?

Comment: Thing is , if all your webapp instance are on the same cassandra cluster you will have to apply the change of schema to the whole cluster at the same time, you cannot change one table on one node only at a time. You could do this migration without downtime using Spark for instance for the data migration but you may miss soem data if the webapps are still active while you do that. I don't see anyway to not stopping all webapps while doing the migration

Comment: My idea, in a nutschell, is to remove one node from the cluster temporarily, apply migrations on it, and then return it, letting it promulgate the schema changes to other nodes. I haven't tried that in practice yet, but I will, and will share my experience here. Based on the Cassandra docs, it should be possible. And I'm talking about schema changes, not data changes. Spark probably is not up to this task.

Comment: Why is the schema incompatible?

Comment: @Haspemulator we also have very similar requirements of upgrading the schema without downtime for apps using old schema. Can you please share the steps that works for you?

Comment: hi did you find these steps ?